# Вызов функций по ключам

Tags: linux, bash, сеть

Мне нужно сделать скрипт, который при вызове без параметров выводит свой функционал, если же скрипт запускается с параметрам "--all", то он выводит хосты которые находятся в данной подсети, если с "target", то он выводит список открытых портов. Но вылазит ошибка:
[image]

```html
#!/bin/bash
function without_key()
{
  echo "--all выводит IP-адреса и символьные имена всех узлов в текущей подсети"
  echo "--target=X.X.X.X выводит список открытых портов TCP "
}
function with_all()
{
echo 192.168.1.{1..254}|xargs -n1 -P0 ping -c1|grep "bytes from"
}
function with_target()
{
netstat -ntulp
}

string1="--all"
string2="--target"

if [ -z $1 ]
then
without_key
elif [$1 = $string1]
then
with_all
elif [$1 = $string2]
then
with_target
fi
```

Comment: Вы пробелы вокруг `[` и `]` забыли поставить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` и `]` не части синтаксиса оболочки.
`[` — команда (её
синоним — `test`), а `]`
 — один из её аргументов.  Поэтому правильно писать
так:

```sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    without_key
elif [ "$1" = "$string1" ]
then
    with_all
elif [ "$1" = "$string2" ]
then
    with_target
fi
```